# vim w0ro/ale tslint doesnt work

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, tslint

I've benn using w0rp/ale for linting with eslint.

I've switched to tslint and the linting stopped working. I have the tslint npm package installed and have tslint.json confing file. Is there something I need to do or should check?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you remember to tell ALE to use tslint in your .vimrc?

Comment: Well no, I did not tell it to use eslint either, and it just used it. I don't know what shoud I configure that's why I am asking, because it he ALE documentation I see nothing on this topic.

What shall I add to my vimrc ?

Comment: run `:help ale_linters` and that should give you an idea of what should be in your .vimrc.